# How to create and manage multiple iframes within a single container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, containers

Alright guys, I want to create a small box for my website, and within that box, I want to create iFrames of links to voting websites. I want it to look something very similar to http://forums.scavengercraft.com/pages/vote/ The part of the page were they have the Vote buttons #1-5, and the fact that each button will pull up the next iframe.

What I currently have:
http://jsfiddle.net/xDU9V/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="outerdiv">  
        <a href="innerdiv">Minestatus</a>
    <iframe id="innerdiv" width="900" height="560" src="https://minestatus.net/15952-factions-goldcraft-1-6-mob-arena-economy-auctions/vote" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what I want to do is add a snazzy little navbar at the top where I currently have the link "Minestatus" and I want each button to load a different website into the iframe.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It page that you show us, use a slider. Each slide contents a div with an iframe. Something like this:

```
<div id="myVote" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item">
      <iframe src="http://minecraftservers.org/vote/64023" class="votebox" seamless="" frameborder="1" height="700" width="100%"></iframe>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Vote #1</h4>
            <p>Make sure you click the &gt; button to vote on all sites for more rewards!</p>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
      <iframe src="http://topg.org/Minecraft/in-374381" class="votebox" seamless="" frameborder="1" height="700" width="100%"></iframe>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Vote #2</h4>
            <p>Make sure you click the &gt; button to vote on all sites for more rewards!</p>
           </div>
      </div> 
    <div class="item">
      <iframe src="http://minecraft-server-list.com/server/85519/vote/" class="votebox" seamless="" frameborder="1" height="700" width="100%"></iframe>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Vote #3</h4>
            <p>Make sure you click the &gt; button to vote on all sites for more rewards!</p>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
      <iframe src="http://minecraft-mp.com/server/6376/vote/" class="votebox" seamless="" frameborder="1" height="700" width="100%"></iframe>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Vote #4</h4>
            <p>Make sure you click the &gt; button to vote on all sites for more rewards!</p>
           </div>
      </div>
    <div class="item">
      <iframe src="https://minestatus.net/43246-scavenger-craft-pvp-dedicated-server/vote" class="votebox" seamless="" frameborder="1" height="700" width="100%"></iframe>
       <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Vote #5</h4>
            <p>Make sure you click the &gt; button to vote on all sites for more rewards!</p>
           </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control left votebox-control" href="#myVote" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right votebox-control" href="#myVote" data-slide="next">›</a>

     </div>
```

Use Firebug to investigate it page!

Comment: Thanks for showing me that! I was wondering though, how do I get them to display one of the iframes in the box at a time? And also, how did they get them to all rotate through, and have the links on that navbar?

Comment: @user3674397 http://jsbin.com/jebot/1/edit , now just put your iframes inside every tab